# Jquery Conditional Formatting - Number Range

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using this Jquery script to highlight column based on the item value within. Is it possible to add a numerical range? i.e. 0-50 returns in green.

Thanks

```
​​​​​​​​​<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> </script><script>
function listFormat() {        
        $Text = $("td .ms-vb-lastCell.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2.ms-vb-lastCell:contains('10%')");
        $Text.css("background-color", "Red");
        $Text = $("td .ms-vb-lastCell.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2.ms-vb-lastCell:contains('20%')");
        $Text.css("background-color", "Yellow");
}
//  This invokes the function defined above once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute:
    $(document).ready(function(){
        listFormat()
}); 
//  This preserves conditional formatting after list filters are applied or cleared:
    window.onhashchange = listFormat;
    
//  Equivalent syntax:
//  window.addEventListener("hashchange", listFormat);
</script> ​​​​​​​​​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the way that you are selecting cells, because you are using the CSS selector `:contains()` to find cells with a specific text value.  You can't use `contains()` for anything other than an exact match.

You could look at ranges if you get the value of the table cells in a usable way in code and then compare it to a range:

```
// this selects _all_ of the table cells that match your CSS selector,
// regardless of their content, and loops through them all
$("td .ms-vb-lastCell.ms-cellstyle.ms-vb2.ms-vb-lastCell").each(function() {

    // inside the loop function, "$(this)" refers to the single table cell
    // that is getting looped over that time through the loop.  you can use
    // jQuery's "text()" function to get the text contents of the cell 
    var cellText = $(this).text();

    // from your code example, it appears as though you are expecting the
    // contents of the cells to be precentages, i.e "10%", "20%", etc.
    // so you can use parseInt() to change the percentage string into
    // an actual number so you can do number comparisons
    var cellPercentValue = parseInt(cellText);

    // then you can do your comparisons, and set the background color
    // accordingly.  remember "$(this)" still refers to the table cell
    if (cellPercentValue >= 50) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    } else if (25 <= cellPercentValue < 50) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } else if (cellPercentValue < 25) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    }
});
```